# Hyper-V Create Virtual Machine Failed

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a windows 2012 R2 server with Hyper-V as a role.
The server has 6 vm already working.
If I use the domain administrator or the local administrator (wich is also in the hyper-v administrator group) to make a new virtual machine i get a very disturbing, undocumented, and not present in the windows event viewer, ERROR.
[image: ERROR]

So I was asking myself if anybody has a solution for that.
In english the message is: The server encountered an error while creating Gestionale, the operation failed.
The virtual machine i am creating is this one
[image: BLANK VM GEN 2 WITH 20GB RAM]

I am quite frustrated by that.
Kindest Regards.

Comment: You should check the Event Viewer for the specific error, and add that to your question.

Comment: all the error events in the hyper-v section, are not giving details.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out after some attempts.
The issue in my case is caused by the fact that the machine has only 10 GB of RAM available.
So the solution is:
shutdown every other vm.
generate a vm with 512 MB dynamic.
power up all the vm.
And then Increase the number of cores and the amount of ram to the maximum available.
I am aware that it sounds very dangerous in a production environment, but the customer has been warned properly.
That is very strange because I would have expected some error log or error message explaining the meaning of the popup window.